# Leaflet bounds with padding

Tags: leaflet

I'm Trying to create caching mechanism instead of bringing the whole map.
right now i use:
 `getBounds()` and receive all the points in the area the user is currently viewing.

What i would like to achieve is Padding for the Bounds.
for example:

```
map.getBounds(50)
```

should bring the bounds the user currently is viewing X2 the area.. or maybe one zoom level lower area.. but without interrupting the user.

currently fitBounds [(JSFiddle Demo Here)](http://jsfiddle.net/72tgL3r1/) does more or less that just resulting in changing the view of the user :( .. I Also tried getting the bounds from the function it self (fitBounds) but it outputs center and zoom not bounds (and i didnt succeed in resulting correct bounds from them)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried the [`pad` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-pad) on the `L.LatLngBounds` you get from `map.getBounds()`? It is specifically made to increase the size of some bounds.

> Returns bigger bounds created by extending the current bounds by a given percentage in each direction.

For example if you want to increase the size of your bounds by 1 view port in each direction, you would do:

```js
var newBounds = map.getBounds().pad(1)
```

Now if you want to double the *area* of the bounds (approximately, not taking projection into account), you would have to increase the *total* length in each axis by sqrt(2), hence increase the bounds in each direction by sqrt(2) / 2:

```js
var doubleAreaBounds = map.getBounds().pad(Math.sqrt(2) / 2)
```

Comment: Amazing! i missed it completely, thank you very much!